# Translate strings in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm still learning python and a lot of basics are still complicated to me. I just started out using codewars.com, and it seems like an awesome tool to learn any of the languages they have set up so far. The only downside is their python is only 2.7, so some of the code has to be modified from 3.0 to work properly. I'm working on one problem now that wants me to convert (I think translate is what I'm looking for) numbers from the keyboard layout to the phone layout. So I'm trying to translate '7894561230' to '1234567890'. Maybe this is entirely the wrong way to go about doing it, but as I said, I'm still learning. Here is the code I have, but it's not working. I think it's because I'm using python 3.... Any suggestions?

```
from string import maketrans
def computer_to_phone(numbers):
    dict = str.maketrans('7894561230', '1234567890')
    result = numbers.translate(dict)
    return result
```

EDIT: Here's the error message I'm getting

```
Traceback:
   in 
   in computer_to_phone
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

Comment: Can you explain not working? What else are you getting?

Comment: Added the error message. Sorry about that.

Comment: Just call it without the `str.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am guessing the issue comes from  line -

```
dict = str.maketrans('7894561230', '1234567890')
```

You are trying to call `str.maketrans` , but you there is not such method  for `str` class , in Python 2.x , you should make use of the `string.maketrans()` you are importing instead -

```
from string import maketrans
def computer_to_phone(numbers):
    dict = maketrans('7894561230', '1234567890')
    result = numbers.translate(dict)
    return result
```

Comment: few seconds quicker than I wanted to post an answer

Comment: you've got to be kidding me..... It's that easy? All those google searches and not one time did I see that listed. Thanks!